# PHP Directory Tree - Deleting Folders

Tags: php, recursion, directory, unlink

I have found a script that lists all directories and files in them, and allows for the deletion of files.

I have two problems:

1) How do I add the function to delete a folder (With all the contents in it)
2) How do I make the script not to allow a user to browse up a directory? (For e.g. a user's folder is `./files/$userid/`. I want it so that a user won't be able to go to or make any changes to `./files/` or a folder other then `./files/$userid/`

```
$script = basename(__FILE__); // the name of this script
                              $path   = !empty($_REQUEST['path']) ? $_REQUEST['path'] : dirname('./files/' . (string)$userid . '/'); // the path the script should access
                              $unlink = $_REQUEST['unlink'];


                              if(!empty($unlink)){
                                $unlink = realpath("$path/$unlink");
                                if(is_writable($unlink) && !unlink($unlink)){
                                  echo "<div class=\"error\">Unable to delete file: $unlink</div>";
                                }
                              }

                              echo "<p>Browsing Location: {$path}</p>";

                              $directories = array();
                              $files       = array();

                              // Check we are focused on a dir
                              if (is_dir($path)){
                                chdir($path); // Focus on the dir
                                if ($handle = opendir('.')){
                                  while (($item = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
                                    // Loop through current directory and divide files and directorys
                                    if(is_dir($item)){
                                      array_push($directories, realpath($item));
                                    }
                                    else{
                                      array_push($files, ($item));
                                    }
                                  }

                                  closedir($handle); // Close the directory handle
                                }
                                else {
                                  echo "<p class=\"error\">Directory handle could not be obtained.</p>";
                                }
                              }
                              else{
                                echo "<p class=\"error\">Path is not a directory</p>";
                              }

                              // List the directories as browsable navigation
                              echo "<h2>Navigation</h2>";
                              echo "<ul>";
                              foreach($directories as $directory){

                                $delete = is_writable($file) ? "<a class=\"unlink\" href=\"{$script}?path={$path}&unlink={$directory}\">delete</a>" : '';

                                echo ($directory != $path) ? "<li><a href=\"{$script}?path={$directory}\">{$directory}</a></li>" : "";
                              }
                              echo "</ul>";

                              echo "<h2>Files</h2>";
                              echo "<ul>";
                              foreach($files as $file){
                                // Comment the next line out if you wish see hidden files while browsing
                                if(preg_match("/^\./", $file) || $file == $script){continue;} // This line will hide all invisible files.

                                $delete = is_writable($file) ? "<a class=\"unlink\" href=\"{$script}?path={$path}&unlink={$file}\">delete</a>" : '';

                                echo '<li><a href="' . basename($file) . '" target="_blank">' . $file . "</a> $delete</li>";
                              }
                              echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: You can find multiple recursive folder delete scripts under rmdir in PHP manual

Answer (score 1):

1) Try use this function to delete folder recursively (see manual, User contributed notes section http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php):

```
  function delTree($dir) { 
   $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
    foreach ($files as $file) { 
      (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
    } 
    return rmdir($dir); 
  }
```

2) Better develop some filemanager to allow users browse certain folders. Or see some ready solutions: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-file-manager-plugins/